# How to export all children of a family?

Tags: relationships

Our organization has families defined by relationships (but not put into households) and is looking to print a directory with a column of family members:

```
        NAME          FAMILY
        Bob Smith     Susan Smith (spouse)
                      Jimmy Smith (child)
                      Katie Smith (child)
```

I know I can export the spouse display name, but when I export "Individual > Parent of > Display Name" this only lists one child.

How can I export all children?

Comment: Assuming Jimmy and Katie have a relationship "child of" with Susan too, are you expecting to have another "family group" with Susan being the name, and bob the spouse and Jimmy and Katie the children? Having explicit households would help avoiding that too.

Comment: Yes, having another "family group" with Susan being the name was the original intention, but I'm not sure now as it seems redundant.

Comment: I didn't have enough points to comment on Allen Hutchinson's question about my sharing our custom search. Unfortunately, our company was recently sold and while the previous company had an "open source" view point, the new company does not. So sorry. But, you might contact Sarah Gladstone who was the original programmer (sarah@fountaintribe.com)

Answer (score 10):

The relationship report will give you all the children of a contact easily for you. Relationship reports are standard with CiviCRM and appear under Contact Reports.

Edit filters to ensure the relationship is filtering on only the type you're interested in reporting on. You can then export to csv which will allow you to sort as required there if you want them to display in a particular way.

You'll see that it can only filter on one relationship at a time, so if you put all the contacts that you want to include into a group, you can filter on that instead to display all the relationships on contact in that group.

If you are using Drupal, you might also want to explore views to display this information for you. However, if you don't use Drupal or aren't familiar with views, this is a steep learning curve! If you use it in conjuction with views data export (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) you can get the information into excel from the view also.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to combine the children into one row (or would that be done after the .csv export in a spreadsheet program)?

Comment: That's right, you'd need to adjust in csv once you've exported and manipulate the data as you'd like it to be displayed for your directory.

Comment: "I've adjust the example one on the demo site for you to see" Hey Heather O - this gets reset periodically so you might want to explain what you did in this post.

Answer (score 2):

We work with religious congregations and all have this need.  In fact, one of the top things on our wish list is to be able to be able to have a printed directory functionality/export from the CRM.

Because of the challenges with the export and relationship report, we made our own custom search called Couples and Household listing that shows both adults in the household, children, ages of children, membership status and all contact information.  That way, our clients can just export that search and have all the data for their printed directory.

Comment: Dina, is that something you could share? As you've noted, lots of folks would be interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

just to clarify that others have identified this issue. See old threads here: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34656.0 and here: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,26611.msg112915.html#msg112915.
My organisation could also benefit from being able to export this information through the normal 'Export Contacts' or 'Export Participants' interface rather than having to report on it separately. Looks like lots of folks started down the road of capturing data using relationships only to discover the limitations. In fact, there are lots of gaps in Civi where relationships are concerned.