# How to export 'employee of' relationship that has multiple staff members?

Tags: relationships, export, reports

As a disclaimer, I've read up on this thread: [How to export all children of a family?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/800/how-to-export-all-children-of-a-family). However, that doesn't seem to solve my problem. Here's my dilemma.

I'm looking to export contacts from our installation that shows both the organization's employees as well as the staff member assigned to that organization (known as a field support coordinator). We have the relationships 'employee of' and 'field support coordinator is' to handle this.

If I pull up the organizational group 'current affiliates' and export those contacts, we are able to choose the aforementioned relationships. However, with the 'employee of' relationship, it only exports one staff member.

I've tried to alleviate this by using the advanced search to create a group called 'employees of current affiliates' which pulls everyone. I'm able to export this list with the 'employee of' relationship, but then I'm stuck with the inability to export the relationship 'field support coordinator is' since that's only attributed to organizational records.

I've gone to the reporting section and even tried pulling up this information there using the relationships template, but I run into the same issue where I'm not able to show the 'field support coordinator' is relationship, only the 'employee of' relationship.

Finally, I've tried creating a Drupal view which works fine, however the same issue occurs where it only shows one 'employee of' and not the multiple contact records attributed to it.

Is all of this a limitation of the system? Am I missing something or not understanding what needs to be done? Do we need to go to our developer to get this laid out in a different fashion?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think this is a limitation of the system. It would help if you can screenshot your 'relationship' settings and general set up of the Drupal View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a quick example of a View together which you can download from our [Treasure Trove](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/view-show-people-various-relationship-types-organisation).

It is based on 'contact' and assumes that the Org is at the B end of the relationship, and uses a single 'views' relationship starting from B to then connect to Contact A, and the 'which Civi relationship to use' has been set to include several - but these will need reselecting based on which civi Relationships you are trying to pull in.

Hope it makes sense. It may not be quite where you were headed but may gave you some ideas in how to put your View together.

I think an alternative could be to build the View based on CiviCRM Relationship, rather than CiviCRM Contact.